# Error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paquete'

Tags: python

mi problema es el siguiente estoy haciendo un curso en el que me enseñan a usar modulos y paquetes, yo tengo una carpeta que posee 2 cosas, un SCRIPT (desde el cual trato de importar un paquete) y  una carpeta (llamada paquete, donde poseo 2 archivos, un **init** y u script con funciones que deseo importar en el primer script). La cosa es que cuando ejecuto el codigo para importar en el primer script me salta este error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paquete'.

¿Como puedo solucionarlo para que me importe lo que necesito? Adjunto fotos(La primera es la de la carpeta que posee el script y el paquete, la segunda es del contenido de mi paquete y la tercera es de mi codiog en python y el error que me devuelve)
El codigo que use fue:

from paquete.saludos import *

Saludo()

[image: En el archivo llamado script es donde quiero importar mi paquete, y la carpeta paquete es donde tengo lo que quiero importar]

[image: Este es el contenido de la carpeta paquete]

[image: En esta foto muestro el codigo que quiero ejecutar y el error que me devuelve].

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapida respuesta y por el link a como hacer buenas preguntas, lo voy a leer, por otro lado probé el codigo que me proporcionaste y me sigue devolviendo el mismo error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paquete'.

Answer (score 0):

## Para empezar...

Lo que estas realizando al hacer esto `from paquete.saludos` es llamar al subpaquete `saludos`. Lo que Python esta haciendo es buscar ir a `sys.path` y busca el subdirectorio del paquete.

Al agregar `import *` lo que esta ocurriendo es que o lo que esperariamos idealmente que ocurriera es esta instruccion fuera directamente al sistema de archivos, encontrara todos los submódulos presentes en el paquete y los importara. Pero, pero, p e r o esto llevaría mucho tiempo y podría tener efectos secundarios no deseados (solo en caso de que el modulo se importe explícitamente.

## Entonces...

La solución seria proporcionar un índice explicito de los submódulos del paquete.

Los archivos `__init__.py` son necesarios para que Python trate los directorios que contienen el archivo como paquetes. Esto evita que los directorios con un nombre común, como por ejemplo `string`, oculten involuntariamente módulos válidos que aparecen más adelante en la ruta de búsqueda del módulo. En el caso más simple, `__init__.py` puede ser simplemente un archivo vacío, pero también puede ejecutar código de inicialización para el paquete.

El `import` utiliza la siguiente convicción: si el código del paquete `__init__.py` define una lista llamada `__all__` que vendría siendo el índice de módulos que se podrían importar cuando se define `from paquete.saludos import *`

Si el `__all__` no esta definido entonces no se importan los submódulos del paquete, es como si no existieran y a raíz de eso, creo, nace el error.

## Para aclarar...

No soy un experto, tendría que venir uno par ayudarte mas específicamente o mas claramente en caso de que yo este mal. Todo lo que te acabo de comentar [en la documentacion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) por si quieres leerlo y ver si te queda mas claro.

Lo que recomendaría ahora es definir en `__init__.py` la lista `__all__` con los nombres de los submódulos.

Solo agregaría que importar de esta manera se considera una mala practica por los efectos inesperados que pueda aparecer, por ejemplo que algún modulo comparta nombre.

Tampoco se muy bien que tratas de hacer con `saludos` ¿es una funciona? ¿un método? ¿una clase? Se llamaría de manera diferente según que sea...

Probé haciendo algo así(considerando lo que creo seria una buena practica):

> En carpeta Paquete

`__init__.py`

vacio

`saludos.py`

```
class Saludo():
    def hola(self, nombre, s_hola):
        self.nombre= nombre
        self.hola= s_hola
        
        print(f"Hola {nombre}, {self.hola}")
```

> En carpeta madre(?)

`script.py`

```
from Paquete import saludos

s = saludos.Saludo()

s.hola("Ramon", "¿Como estas?")
```

Y funciona perfecto...

## Ahora

Aplicando todo lo que te dije anteriormente quedaría algo así(tomando en consideración que no se considera una buena practica):

> En carpeta Paquete

`__init__.py`

```
__all__ = ["hola"]
```

`saludos.py`

```
def hola(nombre, s_hola):
    print(f"Hola {nombre}, {s_hola}")
```

> En carpeta madre(?)

`script.py`

```
from Paquete.saludos import *

s= hola("Ramon", "¿Como estas?")
```

E igual funciona perfecto...
Espero haberte ayudado:)

Comment: Me temo que ahora los paquetes son algo más sofisticados. Lo que describes son los paquetes regulares. También hay paquetes _namespaces_ que no requieren ficheros `__init__.py`. Así mismo, también se pueden hacer importaciones de módulos con rutas relativas. Más info: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Oh, desconocía eso por completo. Lo que describí en mi respuesta también lo desconocía hace media hora XD así que: ¡Muchas gracias! Le echare una leída.