# problemas con importar modulo: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usuarios'

Tags: python-3.x, vscode, module.exports

Les deseo un buen día.
Estoy haciendo un curso de Udemy "Master en Python" y estoy trancado en importar un modulo que yo mismo he creado.
Cree el modulo usuario.py donde cree la clase usuario con sus funciones.
Debo importar el modulo usuario en otro modulo llamado acciones.py pero al ejecutar me arroja error: import usuarios.usuario as modelo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usuarios'

Alguien que me ayude por favor.
Ya cambie el entorno y el interprete. He instalado y desinstalado todo y aún nada.

Adjunto imagen

[image: Pantallazo de todo]

'''

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime

database = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "",
    database = "master_python",
    port = 3306
)

cursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)

class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, email, password):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.apellidos = apellidos
    self.email = email
    self.password = password

    def registrar(self):
        fecha = datetime.datetime.now
        sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (null, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        usuario = (self.nombre, self.apellidos, self.email, self.password, 
                  fecha)

        cursor.execute(sql, usuario)
        database.commit()

        return [cursor.rowcount, self]

    def identificar(self):
        return self.nombre

import usuarios.usuario as modelo

class Acciones:
    def registro(self):
        print("\nOk, vamos a registrarte en el sistema...")
        nombre = input("Cual es tu nombre?: ")
        apellidos = input("Cuales son tus apellidos?: ")
        email = input("Introduce tu email: ")
        password = input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")

        usuario = modelo.Usuario(nombre, apellidos, email, password)
        registro = usuario.registrar()

        if registro[0] >= 1:
            print(f"Perfecto {registro[1].nombre}, te has registrado con 
            el mail {registro[1].email}")
    
        else:
            print("No te has registrado correctamente")

        def login(self):
            print("\nOk, identificate...")
            email = input("Introduce tu email: ")
            password = input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")
```

Comment: Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427636/error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-paquete/427665#427665) creo que puede ayudarte, también hay un comentario referido a documentación con información mas actualizada.

Comment: Gracias @candidMoe, ya lo he editado.

Comment: Gracias @logicaMiau lo estoy revisando.

Answer (score 0):

Se que es tarde pero para los que siguen con el problema usen pycharm y cambien en `acciones.py`

```py
from usuarios import usuario as modelo
```

por

```
from . import usuario as modelo
```

y les deberia funcionar.